# Interfaces: Convert My existing concrete code to an abstract code

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, abstraction

I am working on a UWP app. I have a PCL that has managers and services. My managers interact with my services and provide the output. In my services I use async await calls for interacting with my API. I've created a dummy solution. The code is as below:

**My Dummy Managers:**

```
public class AccountManager
{

    public string uniqueId { get; set; }

    public int GetAccountId()
    {
        Services.AccountServices HelloAccount = new Services.AccountServices();
        return HelloAccount.GenerateAccountId(uniqueId);
    }
}

public class DummyManager
{

    public ICollection<string> GetDeviceNames(int accountId)
    {
        Services.NameService MyNameService = new Services.NameService(accountId);
        return MyNameService.ProvideNames();
    }
}
```

**My Dummy Services:**

```
 internal class NameService
{
    public NameService(int Id)
    {
        AccountId = Id;
    }

    public int AccountId = 0;

    public ICollection<string> ProvideNames()
    {
        return new List<string>()
        {
            "Bob",
            "James",
            "Foo",
            "Bar"
        };
    }

}

 internal class AccountServices
{

    public int GenerateAccountId(string uniqueID)
    {
        return 11;
    }

}
```

Now that I have my services and managers the same structure as I use them, below is how I interact with my `Public Managers` and keeping the `services` `internal`:

**In my UI MainPage CodeBehind:**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        DataServices.Managers.AccountManager Hello = new DataServices.Managers.AccountManager();
        Hello.uniqueId = "AsBbCc";    //fetched from another service.
        var id = Hello.GetAccountId();

        DataServices.Managers.DummyManager Dummy = new DataServices.Managers.DummyManager();
        var names = Dummy.GetDeviceNames(id);
    }
```

---

My Question is currently my MainPage is very Tightly coupled with my `manager` and even if I use the MVVM pattern, then my ViewModel would be Tightly coupled with my managers. How do I add a layer of abstraction? What out of these entities (Managers, services, DataBank) should be an `Interface` that helps to provide abstraction? I need help. I've uploaded a dummy solution for the same. Thanks :)

[My Entire dummy solution](https://1drv.ms/u/s!As_vb6rIH1MBgaowtFw7QD2HJoh1zA) for better understanding.

Comment: All services should expose an interface.  All UI View Models should consume the interface (typically constructor injection).  Implemenations should be wired up in the Composition Root with their associated interfaces.

Comment: @youzer can you please help with a sample code? If I getting it right, My managers must be moved to services, The concrete services must implement an Interface which is exposed outside my library project. My ViewModels / CodeBehind must interact with those interfaces inorder to get the result? Is this what you mean? if yes, can you share a code snippet of how to make the viewModel interact with the interface given that the concrete implementation of the interface is internal(restricted to the Library) and if to do so, I have to make the concrete implementation   public, why to use interface?

Answer (score 0):

As shown here, the managers add little (in fact: *no*) value, so why have them? [Refactoring](http://amzn.to/YPdQDf) explicitly talks about this situation and suggests the *Inline Class* refactoring.

> How do I add a layer of abstraction?

That is quite a broad question, and depends on various circumstances, most important of which is: *Which problem are you hoping to solve by adding a layer of abstraction?*

FWIW, my book [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://amzn.to/12p90MG) contains a comprehensive MMVM example, although in WPF, instead of UWP.